# How to recompute styles of an element in firefox extension

Tags: jquery, css, firefox-addon, xul

In my firefox extension, When creating an element, All the styles got applied correctly. But when I alter its content using jquery, `$('#blahblah').html(responseText)`, It loses all its styles, but still correct classes are there to each element.

I think this is a problem with firefox losing computed styles and not computing it again. Is there a way to force firefox to compute styles again to a particular element or the whole page.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a bug in firefox, only thing i can think of is before you alter the html make a var of the class the element has and then do `$('#blahblah').removeClass(class).html(responseText).addClass(class)` so that firefox recomputes them?